# Failed to load --Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Tags: angularjs

Angular JS - When I am trying refresh this page. it is showing the following error:
`** angular.js:12587 Failed to load file:///E:/Programs/Practices%20Programs/employeeTable.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.**`

Comment: you need a web server to run angularjs.  You cannot just run it from your local disk.

Comment: could you please tell me. how will i do? i am new to Angular JS

Comment: just like any other web site, you need a server.  IIS, Node.Js, apache, your choice.  Angular doesn't care what server you use, but you must use one.

Comment: Thank u so much.... Chgsilva